# Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but Runnable! was expected

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I am new to Kotlin and I am trying to build an android camera app that uses machine learning and object detection, using the MLKit and CameraX libraries.

I have the following code in my CameraActivity.kt file, but I am getting the following errors (locations commented in code):

"Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but Runnable! was expected" //ERROR 1

"Type mismatch: inferred type is (???) -> Unit but ImageAnalysis.Analyzer was expected" //ERROR 2

Thanks for your help!

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.util.Size
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.core.UseCase
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.video.Metadata.builder
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import com.example.gapt.databinding.ActivityCameraBinding
import com.example.gapt.utils.Draw
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
import com.google.mlkit.common.model.LocalModel
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.ObjectDetection
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.ObjectDetector
import com.google.mlkit.vision.objects.custom.CustomObjectDetectorOptions
import java.util.concurrent.Executor
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream.builder

class CameraActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityCameraBinding

    private lateinit var objectDetector: ObjectDetector
    private lateinit var cameraProviderFuture: ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_camera)

        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        //ERROR 1
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()}, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))

        val localModel = LocalModel.Builder()
            .setAbsoluteFilePath("object_detection.tflite")
            .build()

        val customObjectDetectorOptions = CustomObjectDetectorOptions.Builder(localModel)
            .setDetectorMode(CustomObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
            .enableClassification()
            .setClassificationConfidenceThreshold(0.5f)
            .setMaxPerObjectLabelCount(3)
            .build()

        objectDetector = ObjectDetection.getClient(customObjectDetectorOptions)

    }

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
    private fun bindPreview(cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider){
        val preview = Preview.Builder().build()

        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build()

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)

        val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(Size(1280, 720))
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .build()
        
        //ERROR 2
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), { imageProxy ->

            val rotationDegrees = imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
            val image = imageProxy.image

            if(image != null){
                val processImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(image, rotationDegrees)

                objectDetector
                    .process(processImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { objects ->
                        for(i in objects) {

                            if(binding.parentLayout.childCount > 1)
                                binding.parentLayout.removeViewAt(1)

                            val element = Draw(context = this,
                                rect = i.boundingBox,
                                text = i.labels.firstOrNull()?.text ?: "Undefined")

                            binding.parentLayout.addView(element)
                        }

                        imageProxy.close()
                    }.addOnFailureListener{
                        Log.v("CameraActivty", "Error - ${it.message}")
                        imageProxy.close()
                    }
            }
        })

        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis, preview)

    }
}
```

Comment: For the first one, I don't see why it should complain, but you can force it to treat the lambda as a Runnable by preceding the first brace with `Runnable`, i.e. `...addListener(Runnable {val cameraProvider ...` For the second one, you need a second lambda parameter (degrees) for it to match the signature of that interface, i.e. `... { imageProxy, degrees -> `

Comment: Okay, the first error disappeared but when I introduced "degrees" i.e. `imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), { imageProxy, degrees ->` I now got the following error: "Type mismatch: inferred type is (???, ???) -> Unit but ImageAnalysis.Analyzer was expected"

Comment: Weird, it's the same issue. It's like SAM conversion is not working at all. You could do the same thing as the first one and prepend the lambda with `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer`.

Comment: I don't understand the cause of the error either. I've never seen it happen before. But if prepending your first lambda with `Runnable` fixed the first case, maybe prepending the second lambda with `ImageAnalysis.Analyzer` will fix your second case. Is this a project you created recently? It might be worth checking that all your plugins and dependencies are up to date in your Gradle files.